# Obtener campo de Fecha mediante una subconsulta

Tags: sql-server, sql

Estimados,
Estoy trabajando en la construccion de un stored procedure, necesito obtener un campo de fecha de una Tabla B dependiendo de un estado en particular, mediante una subconsulta en una tabla A, me explico: 
La tabla A contiene un producto y la tabla B almacena los movimientos historicos de algun registro de la tabla A, mediante una query necesito traer los datos de la tabla A y una fecha de un movimiento especifico de la tabla B.

> Tabla A = lead
>
> Tabla B = lead_history

**Query(Contiene un where por un id para trabajar solo por 1 caso, el estado a buscar en la tabla B, es el 14):**

```
select l.*
,(SELECT lh.execution_date FROM lead_history lh join lead l ON lh.lead_id = l.id WHERE lh.lead_state_id=l.lead_state_id ) AS FechaPropuestaGanada
 from lead l where (l.lead_state_id=14) and l.id=22142
```

Resultado de la query ejecutada:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.
```

Nota: La tabla B almacena todos los cambios de estado por cada Producto de la tabla A, pero ningun estado se repite (ej: no existen 2 registros en estado "Ganada" por un producto de la tabla A, solo 1)

Si separo la subquery por un ID de la tabla A en especifico, seria asi:

```
 SELECT lh.execution_date FROM lead_history lh join lead l ON lh.lead_id = l.id WHERE lh.lead_state_id=14 and lh.lead_id = 22142
```

y mi resultado es este :

```
2017-06-21 11:41:22.303
```

Eso es lo que necesito, pero no logro agregarlo a la consulta principal (este resultado se guarda en un campo adicional de la Query principal, con el alias 'FechaPropuestaGanada')

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante clarificador. Las condiciones que estás usando en la subconsulta entregan más de un resultado. Qué quieres hacer en ese caso?. Sería más clarificador si posteas datos de ejemplo y el resultado que quieres obtener, explicando la lógica detrás de ese resultado

Comment: @Lamak necesito obtener 1 solo resultado, lo que hace la subquery es devolver todos los resultados de todos los registros en el estado 14, algo me falta en el where pero no logro obtenerlo

Comment: Como decía en el comentario anterior, sería bueno si puedes postear datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado (también que agregues el tag correspondiente a la versión de SQL Server que estás usando)

Comment: @Lamak ahi agrege mas datos

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no veo para qué necesitas la subquery?, podrías simplemente usar la subconsulta como tu consulta principal

Comment: @Lamak, la consulta principal hace referencia a la tabla A , y contiene subconsultas hacia otras tablas, realizando algo similar a lo que necesito.

Comment: Pero la subconsulta también tiene la tabla A, y podrías usarlo directamente

Comment: Me refiero a por qué no puedes simplemente usar: `SELECT l.*,
  lh.execution_date 
FROM lead_history lh 
INNER JOIN lead l 
 ON lh.lead_id = l.id 
 AND lh.lead_state_id = l.lead_state_id
WHERE l.lead_state_id = 14 AND l.id = 22142;
`

Comment: @Lamak porque mi consulta principal no tiene que apuntar a lead_history, tiene que ser a lead (es el registro principal), lead_history es una tabla que solo guarda historiales de la tabla principal, en mi consulta principal, debo obtener mas datos que hacen referencias a otras tablas, no puedo cambiar esa referencia, puede ser necesario abrir un chat para enviarte mas detalles

Comment: Sorry, no entiendo. La consulta que puse en el comentario te debería dar todos los datos que quieres. Si no es así, te vuelvo a solicitar que publiques datos de ejemplo de ambas tablas y el resultado que te gustaría obtener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segúnlo expuesto en tu pregunta, analizando tu sentencia y al no tener estructura o datos como referencia, puedo decir que la solución sería hacer un **INNER JOIN** así:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM lead AS l
INNER JOIN lead_history AS lh
    ON(l.id = lh.lead_id AND l.lead_state_id = lh.lead_state_id)
WHERE l.lead_state_id = 14 AND l.id = 22142
```

No veo la necesidad de la subconsulta, ya que por lo que veo en tu sentencia, comparas **lead_state_id** de igual forma que el **id**. Saludos.

Comment: justamente necesitaba esto, realizar la condicion dentro del join, muchas gracias! :D

Comment: De nada, fue un gusto ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: @ArielIgnacio sigh. Este es exactamente el mismo código que puse en mi comentario, el cual dijiste que está malo. Deberías tomar más precaución en los comentarios que posteas

Comment: @Lamak no es el mismo, si te fijas, la consulta en esta respuesta apunta a la tabla principal (lead), lo que tu comentaste apunta a la tabla (lead_history), y como te dije, no puedo cambiar la referencia de la tabla principal (lead)

Comment: No me había percatado del comentario de @Lamak, tiene razón en decir que ser un poco mas precavido no estaría mal. En todo caso se aprende todos los días.

Comment: @ArielIgnacio te cuento que el FROM debe apuntar, es decir el pivoteo debe ser sobre la tabla mas grande, como no tenia estructura ni datos me base en tu ejemplo. Pero de ser así lo que ofreció Lamak estaría bien, de todas formas.

Comment: @Rostan y Lamark, lo siento, no soy tan avanzado en el ambito de consultas en SQL server, pero en mi pregunta realizada solo especifique los datos para obtener parte de objetivo total que necesito, de haber indicado mi query completa es totalmente innecesario ya que el resto esta operativo.  y  Rostan, la tabla mas grande es Lead, por eso tu respuesta es correcta, de cambiar la referencia a lead_history(una tabla secundaria) modificaria por completo la consulta completa

Comment: @ArielIgnacio dale todos estamos aprendiendo no te preocupes por ello. Saludos, y de nuevo un gusto haberte ayudado !

Comment: @ArielIgnacio Pues no, el orden de las tablas en el `INNER JOIN` no es importante, pero en fin...